# Get folder names from a directory

Tags: c#, winforms

```
string fullpath = @"c:\User\A\1"

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 { 
   listbox.items.add();
 }
```

I want to show  only the name of folder "A" under the User in the listbox.

I have tried this

```
string patht = @"c:\User";
string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(patht, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
foreach(string file in files)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(file);
}
```

This doesn't show anything

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] of both things you've tried? Also, please don't just type code that doesn't compile. It's unhelpful.

Comment: string patht = @"c:\User";
            string[] files = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(patht, "*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
            foreach(string file in files)
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(file);
            }

This is first one that doesn't show anything

Comment: [edit] your question, don't add a comment.

Comment: On my box I don't have a `C:\User` folder. I do have a `C:\Users` folder. Are you sure that `patht` variable you use is correct?

Comment: Yes path is correct and it is created just for this to be clear

Comment: do you want to show the files inside the folder A or just the folder name "A" ?

Comment: Your code works if the path has files: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8yzfl.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need folder name then use below code. it will give you parent folder names under the provided path.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string patht = @"C:\Windows";
    string[] directories = System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(patht);
    foreach (string d in directories)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(d));
    }
}
```

In case you need child folders also then there will be separate code.